# A standard protocol for exchanging logs and commands between device and PC?

Tags: embedded, protocols

Here's the problem: I've an embedded device which uses serial or USB to send logs and accept commands. Currently it simply prints to logs as text and has a simple CLI where commands can be typed.

<strike>I'd like to change it, so the data is send/received as binary</strike>. Are there any standard protocols designed for the purpose of sending logs/commands/other type of data? I'm not aware of any nor found anything suitable but I want to be sure before inventing a wheel ;)

**EDIT** Ok I've edited the question because the fact that data is binary is no that relevant here.

So far the closest I've found is [Android Debug Bridge protocol](https://code.google.com/p/microbridge/source/browse/trunk/doc/protocol.txt).

Comment: What stops you from reading the binary data?

Comment: First make sure you really, really want it to be binary; doing so adds a bit of complication, both in that you need to invent your own framing scheme (since you can no longer use newlines or spaces as delimiters) and it also makes it harder to debug, since you can't as easily substitute yourself for one end.  Do you actually need the ~50% savings?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It doesn't have to be binary, but it should be flexible enough to allow for carring any type of data. For example, logs could go from the device to pc as text, but commands/response codes as binary data (as it's easier to parse on both ends). I'm thinkng about rolling a simple protocol based on MessagePack but I'd like to find out if theres enything I've missed.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Logs are produced by device, so it just a stream of bytes - what protocol are you looking here? You mentioned also commands. Are these commands to control logging? Filtering? Selecting log buffer? Then I really doubt there is some standard since it's quite heavily dependent on logging capabilities of system and requirements...

Answer (score 0):

The [MIN protocol](https://github.com/min-protocol/min) is designed for a small 8-bit microcontroller with limited RAM to talk to another device over standard serial link. I've documented a "hello world" program running on an Arduino talking to a PC using a FTDI serial-to-USB chip here:

https://kentindell.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/micrcontroller-interconnect-network-min-version-1-0/

It's a binary protocol but the payload is 0-15 bytes. I've used MIN to carry not just binary sensor data but also ASCII data within the payload field and for the PC to log the ASCII to a file.